# UIScrollView not scrolling to the bottom (bounces back) in SSCollectionView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, sstoolkit

I am using a SSCollectionView to show images in a grid. I am having an issue in scrolling. The items on the last row are not shown completely. I would have to scroll down to see them but the scroll view bounces back up (so it doesn't really scroll to them).

SSCollectionView's scroll view is inaccessible to change; only to inspect.

What else can I do here?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like your content size is not adjusted properly. Make sure the `height` of the scroll view's content size is sufficient and adjust it if needed.